# Java/Libgdx ShadowCast Rendering

Tags: java, libgdx, raycasting

After following a tutorial, I was able to form a simple shadowcasting algorithm that casts rays in different directions and connects those rays sorted by angle to form a polygon. Now that that's done with, I want to use this "field of view", in order to only show/render sprites inside that polygon. However, I do not really have an idea of how to do this.

Code in my render() method:

```
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        //Render my stuctues
        for (Structure s : worldStructures)
        {
            for (Vector2[] polygon : s.polygonList)
            {
                float[] vertices = s.getPolygonVectors(polygon);
                shapeRenderer.polygon(vertices);
            }
        }

        //Re-initiate my array
        rayAngles = new float[rays.size()];
        rayPolygon = new float[rays.size()*2];
        //Go through each of my rays, calculate their angle and point of intersection, put the latter in 
        a Map
        //Go through the keyset of my map (T1 values) and find which ray is the closest
        //render a ray according to that point of intersection's values
        Map<Float,PointOfIntersection> angleMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Line2D.Float ray : rays)
        {
            float x2 = 0f;
            float y2 = 0f;
            Vector2 rV = new Vector2(ray.x2-player.getPos().x,ray.y2-player.getPos().y);
            float angle = (float) Math.atan2(rV.y,rV.x);

            Map<Float,PointOfIntersection> closestMap =new HashMap<Float,PointOfIntersection>();
            for(Structure structure : worldStructures) {
                for (Line2D.Float[] segments : structure.getBodySegments()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
                        PointOfIntersection currentInt = getIntersection(ray, segments[i]);
                        if (currentInt != null) {
                            closestMap.put(currentInt.T1, currentInt);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            Float[] allPoints = closestMap.keySet().toArray(new Float[0]);
            if (allPoints.length > 0) {
                float closestPoint = allPoints[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < allPoints.length; i++) {
                    if(allPoints[i]<closestPoint)
                    {
                        closestPoint = allPoints[i];
                    }
                }
                PointOfIntersection closestIntersection = closestMap.get(closestPoint);
                int index = rays.indexOf(ray);
                rayAngles[index] = angle;
                angleMap.put(rayAngles[index],closestIntersection);
                x2 = closestIntersection.pointOfIntersection.x;
                y2 = closestIntersection.pointOfIntersection.y;
            }
            shapeRenderer.line(ray.x1,ray.y1,x2,y2);
        }

        //Sort angles, Make a polygon according to those sorted angles and their point of intersection
        //Lets me connect said polygon clockwise
        Arrays.sort(rayAngles);
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < rayAngles.length; i++, j += 2) {
            PointOfIntersection point = angleMap.get(rayAngles[i]);
            rayPolygon[j] = point.pointOfIntersection.x;
            rayPolygon[j + 1] = point.pointOfIntersection.y;
        }

        System.out.println(rayPolygon.length);
        shapeRenderer.end();
        //Initialize my Region, texture and batch to render the polygon.
        if (gameLightOn) {
            polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(textureSolid), rayPolygon, 
            triangulator.computeTriangles(rayPolygon).toArray());

            poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
            poly.setOrigin(0, 0);
            polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
            polyBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            polyBatch.begin();
            poly.draw(polyBatch);
            polyBatch.end();
        }
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what box2dlights is doing, at least if you use box2d. Just set your ambient light to black to make sure that everything outside your field of view is really hidden.

Comment: Yes, I just think it is more interesting/fun to try and do it myself as I am still learning. I did some research, and am thinking that blending textures might be a good way to achieve this. Still need to try it.